# Left join not bringing all results when you also select a list of other objects in EFCore 3.1.11

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let me just preface this with acknowledging that this bug no longer occurs with newer versions of EFCore (5+), but unfortunately we cannot update our project right now.

I created a sample code in order to better show how this bug happens. In this sample code I have a DbContext with three tables: Companies, Locations and Employees. A company can have 1 or more employees, and 0 or more locations. I want to create a query of companies and locations that would return like this:

```
Company   | Location   | Employees
-----------------------------------------------
Company 1 | Location 1 | Employee 1, Employee 2
Company 1 | Location 2 | Employee 1, Employee 2
Company 2 |            | Employee 3, Employee 4
```

Different locations for the same company should be in separate lines, and if the company doesn't have a location, it should still show up.

I came up with the following query using Linq, and it does what I described above in EFCore 5+, but not in 3.1.11

```
(from c in ctx.Companies

join _l in ctx.Locations on c.Id equals _l.CompanyId into lGroup
from l in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

where
c.Id == new Guid("FFF461F3-9E38-4DA0-8B31-AC4D0C90A4D0") // Id of Company 1 in the code block above

select new
{
    CompanyName = c.Name,
    LocationName = l == null ? string.Empty : l.Name,
    Employees = c.Employees.Select(e => e.Name)
}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

In EFCore 5+ this returns two items in the resulting list, exactly like I wanted. But in 3.1.11 it returns only one line, with the first location. The second line with the second location is missing.

The thing is, if you change the query to not use the DefaultIfEmpty() (basically changing it from a left join to an inner join) it works exactly as intended, but in that case if you try querying a company with no locations, it won't show up (since it's an inner join with location).

Does anyone know if there's a way I could achieve this in an efficient manner?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: This is the generated query:

```
SELECT [c].[Name], CASE
    WHEN [l].[Id] IS NULL THEN N''
    ELSE [l].[Name]
END, [c].[Id], [e].[Name], [e].[Id]
FROM [Companies] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Locations] AS [l] ON [c].[Id] = [l].[CompanyId]
LEFT JOIN [Employees] AS [e] ON [c].[Id] = [e].[CompanyId]
WHERE [c].[Id] = 'f2c44d70-d713-42dc-b92a-e93b175fc351'
ORDER BY [c].[Id], [e].[Id]
```

Comment: I see you have many to many relations. Do you have a third table?  net core 3.1 ef needs the third table for many-to-many.

Comment: In this case there's no many to many relationship. The company has many locations, each of which has one company, and many employees, each of which has one company. There's no relation between employee and location. It's just a sample I came up with, but in the original there's no reason to be a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Can you please add generated SQL ?

Comment: Added the generated query to the post @GuruStron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add join with `Employees` and handle the result in memory:

```
(from c in ctx.Companies

join _l in ctx.Locations on c.Id equals _l.CompanyId into lGroup
from l in lGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join _e in ctx.Employees on c.Id equals _e.CompanyId into eGroup
from e in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
c.Id == new Guid("FFF461F3-9E38-4DA0-8B31-AC4D0C90A4D0") 

select new
{
    CId = c.Id,
    CompanyName = c.Name,
    LId = l.Id, 
    LocationName = l == null ? string.Empty : l.Name,
    EmployeeName = e.Name
})
.AsNoTracking()
.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => new {CId, LId})
.Select(g = > new 
{
    CompanyName = g.First().CompanyName ,
    LocationName = g.First().LocationName ,
    Employees = g.Select(e => e.EmployeeName)
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var q= ctx.Locations
       .Include(i=>i.Company)
        .Select (i=> new
     {
    CompanyName = i.Company.Name,
    LocationName =i.Name,
    Employees = i.Company.Employees.Select(e => e.Name)
}).AsNoTracking().ToList()
.Union(
    ctx.Companies
       .Where(i=>i.Locations==null)
        .Select (i=> new
     {
    CompanyName = i..Name,
    LocationName =stringEmpty,
    Employees = i.Employees.Select(e => e.Name)
}).AsNoTracking().ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for EFC 3.1 is to split the query on two parts: server side (LINQ to Entities) query selecting only the data needed, but with "normal" collection type projection of correlated sub collections, and client side (LINQ to Objects) query doing the desired flattening / multiplication.

Something like this

```
(from c in ctx.Companies
 select new
 {
     CompanyName = c.Name,
     Locations = c.Locations.Select(e => new { e.Name }), // <-- the data needed
     Employees = c.Employees.Select(e => e.Name),
 })
.AsEnumerable() // <-- switch to client side context
.SelectMany(c => c.Locations.DefaultIfEmpty(), (c, l) => new
{
    c.CompanyName,
    LocationName = l == null ? string.Empty : l.Name,
    c.Employees
}).ToList();
```

In case you don't have `c.Locations` collection navigation property (as you should), replace it with its equivalent

```
ctx.Locations.Where(e => e.CompantyId == c.Id)
```

which is what EFC does automatically with collection navigation properties inside L2E query.